# Logic in Finding the accuracy of user selected point to ideal one

Tags: logic

I am stuck at this point where I need to find the accuracy of the user selection.

This is my case : I have an image of height and width $h and $w. and there is an ideal point in the image namely $x,$y(Co-ordinates). User selects a coordinate which is $x1,$y1.
What I am trying to find is. how close, or how accurate is the user selection to the ideal selection.

Looking for the output in percentage.

Not looking for the code, just the logic.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I will search what that is! :)

Comment: "f" means "an arbitrary function".

Comment: @JanDvorak - I was talking about Euclidean distance lol. Just read about it. Seems useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could measure the absolute distance from the ideal point and then apply a fall-off function. One possible choice is the gaussian function `e^-(d^2)`.

So, one possible formula is

`rating = e^{-[(x-xi)^2+(y-yi)^2]/radius^2}`

where `radius` is the distance from the ideal location that gives the user the rating of `e^-1` (38%). You can choose the radius based on your preference and then tweak it based on how strict you want your rating function to be. You could, for example, choose the radius to be 1/5 of the image diagonal.

Explanation:

- `dist^2 = (x-xi)^2 + (y-yi)^2` computes the square of the euclidean distance (pythagoras' formula).
- `scaled^2 = dist^2 / radius^2` scales the distance
- `e^-(scaled^2)` is the gaussian distribution.

You can't get much better than that if you want:

- the function to be radially symmetric (you have to compute the euclidean distance or its square)
- the function to be reasonably scaled (one pixel is not a reasonable scale)
- the function to fall off from [0;1] to [+inf;0] (e^-d^2 does that perfectly)

Here is a plot of the gaussian function with the aforementioned radius marked in red.
[image: gaussian function]

Comment: Am sorry, what is `radius` again?

Comment: HHmm just saw the edit. I was looking for something more straight and simple like the Euclidean Distance that other one suggested. Not discarding yours, but seems a bit complex. (I do know my question is a bit complex.)

Comment: @Kishor The other one was me as well. This formula computes the square of the euclidean distance, scales it appropriately and applies the gaussian falloff.

Comment: I actually dont know whats Gaussian fall off so I am unsure what that does.Seeing your other comment, I think the final result is going to be some ration between the Euclidean distance and the total size of the image. Is gaussian function something to do that?

Comment: If you want a ratio of distances, you can do just that. `max(0, 1-(d_max/sqrt((x-xi)^2+(y-yi)^2))`